# Cannot switch, ssh to specific user: su: cannot set user id: Resource temporarily unavailable?

Tags: ulimit, java, resources, nexus

`/var/log/secure`:

```
su: pam_keyinit(su-l:session): Unable to change UID to 500 temporarily
su: pam_keyinit(su-l:session): Unable to change UID to 500 temporarily
su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user adtech by root(uid=0)
su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user adtech
```

I guess this is caused by per-user limit, but there is no different when comparing with another user.

Here're `ulimit -n` for `adtech`:

```
[adtech@hmaster87 root]$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 192025
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 655360
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

and this one for `quanta`:

```
[quanta@hmaster87 ~]$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 192025
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 655360
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

the number of processes running by `adtech`:

```
[root@hmaster87 ~]# ps -U adtech | wc -l
25
```

Any other thing to check?

---

**UPDATE Sat Jul 21 09:21:26 ICT 2012:**

```
# getent passwd adtech
adtech:x:500:502::/home/adtech:/bin/bash
```

As I said in the below comment, my co-worker had found out the process which maybe the culprit:

`adtech   12901     1  0 08:58 ?        00:00:00 /home/adtech/nexus/bin/../bin/jsw/linux-x86-64/wrapper /home/adtech/nexus/bin/../bin/jsw/conf/wrapper.conf wrapper.syslog.ident=nexus wrapper.pidfile=/home/adtech/nexus/bin/../bin/jsw/linux-x86-64/nexus.pid wrapper.daemonize=TRUE`

`adtech   12903 12901  1 08:58 ?        00:00:24 java -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=3600 -DbundleBasedir=. -Djava.io.tmpdir=./tmp -DjettyContext=nexus.properties -DjettyContextIncludeKeys=bundleBasedir -DjettyPlexusCompatibility=true -Djava.library.path=bin/jsw/lib -classpath bin/jsw/lib/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:./lib/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:./conf/ -Dwrapper.key=ejxHaBJASiFkAB8w -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=12901 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher ./conf/jetty.xml`

By killing this process the problem go away but we still don't know which limit was exceeded.

---

**UPDATE Sat Dec 15 00:56:13 ICT 2012:**

The @**favadi**'s answer is right, but I update here in case someone google's this thread.

The log file said that:

```
jvm 1    | Server daemon died!
jvm 1    | java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.privilegedStopInner(WrapperManager.java:3152)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.handleSocket(WrapperManager.java:3797)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.run(WrapperManager.java:4084)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Apologies if this is too obvious, but is there a userID 500 on your system? Does it relate to a userName that would be using? Good luck.

Comment: Sure, `adtech` user has UID 500. See my updated. My co-worker had found out the process which is culprit. By killing this process the problem go away but we still don't know which limit was exceeded: open files does not, number of processes does not, maybe memory or anything else. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try attaching strace -f -p to that process and looking for obviously failing syscalls and what they are trying to do...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It could be possible that the `max user processes              (-u) 1024` is too low.

Remember that processes and threads are counting together.
You can use `ps -eLF | grep adtech | wc -l` to show your current value.

Comment: More precisely, it should be `ps -eLF -U adtech | wc -l`.

Comment: If you're wondering where that's set, look in /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf (assuming you're on a RH system).

Comment: @mricon checking `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf` returns `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf: No such file or directory` on CentOS7

Comment: @Utrecht well, you could have done a "ls" in /etc/security/limits.d/ and noticed that on EL-7 it's called "20-nproc.conf", which would have probably been faster than asking it here.

Comment: @quanta, to be more precise, it should be `ps -LF -U adtech | wc -l`. When using the `-e` option you also get other users processes.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the jvm log for evidence it is hitting resource limits. Stack size might be the problem, depending how many java threads the killed process was running.

Searching on your error message finds bug reports for pam_keyinit: check with your vendor's repository whether an updated version is available.

Comment: +1. I forgot the lesson: take a look at the log when getting the problem. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The error was reported by `pam_keyinit`.  Since I am not familiar with this module, I searched for documentation and found this [manpage](http://man.he.net/man8/pam_keyinit).  Based on the description, I wonder if perhaps the process that you killed prevented the necessary access to some files that pam_keyinit needs to modify?  Hopefully this gives you some direction.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen if the user's process-run-limit is reached. The process limit can be increased by editing: `/etc/security/limits.conf` file with a user having root permission. The entry to check will be similar to:

```
*          hard     nproc         100
```

No need to restart any services.

Comment: In my case raising the hard limit had no immediate effect; I had to change the soft one.